# Infopath form - Ensuring unique values

Tags: infopath

I am creating an Info Path form which has a very basic survey. The user has to select the priority from 1 to 10. For this i am using text boxes at the end of each question and user needs to manually enter the number. Now I want to make sure the values are not repeated. Means, they select 1 for a question, they should not use 1 again for any other question. Is it achievable ?

I am not using drop down boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript. Add the below code in `PreSaveAction` function to check for duplicates:

```
function check(){

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var arr = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
   ids = elements[i].id;
   val = elements[i].value;
   if(val == 'null'){
      val = 0;
   }
   arr.push(val);
}
var sorted_arr = arr.sort(); 
var current = null;
var cnt = 0;
msg = '';
for (var i = 0; i <= sorted_arr.length; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i] != current) {
        if (cnt > 1) {
            msg += current + ' occurs --> ' + cnt + ' times\n';
        }
        current = sorted_arr[i];
        cnt = 1;
    } else {
        cnt++;
    }
}

if (msg != '') {
    alert('Please remove duplicates:\n'+msg);
    return false;
} 

}
```